# What does this symbol mean in logic (rotated up-tick)?

Tags: logic

What does this symbol mean in logic?

[image]

P.S.: up tick would mean contradiction (always-false logic constant), but this is not up-tick (falsum).

Is this synonym for implication (material condition -> ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"$x ⊢ y$ means $y$ is provable from $x$ (in some specified formal system)" - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logic_symbols

Also it is called a 'turnstile' and its Wiki page is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turnstile_(symbol)).